Error during run flutter (Run without debugging / Start Debugging)
Try to run flutter apps via Visual studio code and emulator. (Press F5 or Control F5) showing error as below...
=====================
Launching lib\\main.dart on sdk gphone x86 64 in debug mode...

main.dart:1

2

Invalid depfile: C:\\Ayah\\FlutterDart\\flutter_nodejs_mysql_one\\.dart_tool\\flutter_build\\8d96c09052f6e7f982d832680347c2a5\\kernel_snapshot.d

Unhandled exception:

FileSystemException(uri=org-dartlang-untranslatable-uri:dart%3Ajs; message=StandardFileSystem only supports file:\* and data:\* URIs)

#0      StandardFileSystem.entityForUri (package:front_end/src/api_prototype/standard_file_system.dart:34:7)

#1      asFileUri (package:vm/kernel_front_end.dart:721:37)

#2      writeDepfile (package:vm/kernel_front_end.dart:861:21)

\<asynchronous suspension\>

#3      FrontendCompiler.compile (package:frontend_server/frontend_server.dart:660:9)

\<asynchronous suspension\>

#4      starter (package:frontend_server/starter.dart:99:12)

\<asynchronous suspension\>

#5      main (file:///C:/b/s/w/ir/x/w/sdk/pkg/frontend_server/bin/frontend_server_starter.dart:13:14)

\<asynchronous suspension\>

Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception

2

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

\* What went wrong:

Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.

\\> Process 'command 'C:\\src\\flutter\\bin\\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

\* Try:

\\> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.

\\> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

\\> Run with --scan to get full insights.

\* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 7s

Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Exited (sigterm)

=====================
This error never happen before..
Appriciated kind help...
